# Codename One - What does it happen if a thread crashes or blocks?

Tags: codenameone

In the second lesson of the module "**Performance & Memory Tuning**" of the Codename One Academy *(course "Deep Dive into Mobile Development with Codename One")*, there is an example of optimization using the static method `com.codename1.ui.CN.startThread(Runnable r, String name)`.

Is it exactly the same (about crash protection and other functionalities) if I use the static method `com.codename1.util.EasyThread.start(String name).run(Runnable r)`? I have this doubt because the **[Javadoc of `startThread`](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/CN.html#startThread-java.lang.Runnable-java.lang.String-)** explicitly refers to the crash protection, while the [**Javadoc of `EasyThread`**](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/util/EasyThread.html) doesn't.

In general, what does it happen if a thread crashes or blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EasyThread` uses `startThread` internally so it should be fine. The behavior in case of a crash varies based on the OS and this matters a lot because the native OS can start its own threads where we have limited control.

On iOS we convert illegal access and similar errors to Java exceptions so they should traverse the stack and might reach out generic catch all statements but this isn't foolproof.